# Use onActivityResult when button IsClicked

Tags: android, android-intent, onactivityresult

I have an activity that once a `ToggleButton` is clicked, it starts another activity as follows:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ChatActivity.this, BBActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(intent,1);
```

In that second activity it performs few calculations and then:

```
confirmedData.putExtra( "confirmedB", (Serializable) bSelected );
confirmedData.putExtra( "dateInMillis",DateInMillis );
setResult(ChatActivity.RESULT_OK,confirmedData);
```

Then, I use the following to get the results in my first activity:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if(resultCode == ChatActivity.RESULT_OK){
            ArrayList<DiscoverB> confirmedB = (ArrayList<DiscoverB>)data.getSerializableExtra("confirmedB");
            Long DateInMillis = data.getLongExtra( "dateInMillis", System.currentTimeMillis());
            Log.d("ERROR", "error");
        }
        if (resultCode == ChatActivity.RESULT_CANCELED) {

        }
    }
}
```

Now, I had like to use `confirmedB` Once a button in my activity is clicked.

How can I pass the values from onActivityResult to my `ClickListener`?

```
ChatAdapter.OnConfirmClickListener confirmListener = new ChatAdapter.OnConfirmClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(Button confirmB) {

        ???myarraylist = onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)???
        HERE I NEED MY confirmedB

    }
};
```

Thank you

Comment: store the value which are returned from `onActivityResult` on a global variable 
then in button click you can check if this variable has a value then proceed with what you want

Answer (score 0):

In your first activity, declare a variable

```
ArrayList<DiscoverB> confirmedB;
```

In OnActivityResult, you can initialize confirmedB

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if(resultCode == ChatActivity.RESULT_OK){
            confirmedB = (ArrayList<DiscoverB>)data.getSerializableExtra("confirmedB");
            Long DateInMillis = data.getLongExtra( "dateInMillis", System.currentTimeMillis());
            Log.d("ERROR", "error");
        }
        if (resultCode == ChatActivity.RESULT_CANCELED) {

        }
    }
}
```

You can use it now in your clickListener,

```
ChatAdapter.OnConfirmClickListener confirmListener = new ChatAdapter.OnConfirmClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(Button confirmB) {

        ???myarraylist = onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)???
       here you can use confirmedB

    }
};
```